# DATEADD equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, equivalent, dateadd

Is there an equivalent to this T-SQL command in PostgreSQL?

```
select dateadd(hh,duration_in_hours,start_date) as end_date
```

I have found only interval keyword with subsequent string, but this terrible construction returns syntax error:

```
select start_date + interval cast(duration_in_hours as varchar) || ' hours'
```

It allows only string constant after "interval " keyword. I am sure there must be some similar function in pgsql, but I cannot find it.

Comment: True, it is the same. I couldn't find it using my keywords.

Comment: Actually `INTERVAL` is a type, so you can cast a string as such. Your statement could be rewritten as `select start_date + cast(duration_in_hours ||  ' hours' as INTERVAL)`; I got irritated and wrapped the whole thing into a simple function: `create or replace function dateadd(date,float,char) returns date as
 $$
 begin
  return $1 + cast($2||' '||$3 as interval);
 end;
 $$ language plpgsql;`. Excuse the spacing.

Comment: You can try a UDF. I wrote one here. https://gist.github.com/danielleevandenbosch/1fbe392fd9e2d91952a1b029351e4fcb

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select start_date + (duration_in_hours * interval '1 hour') from your_table
```

See this [sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/08bf0/2)

Comment: what if duration_in_hours is null? can you make it like `duration_in_hours ? duration_in_hours: 1`

Comment: @user151496 then `COALESCE(duration_in_hours, 1)`