# Adding months to a date with dateadd

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a set of data that looks similar to this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a third field, let's call it `length`, which takes the `created_date` field and gives you a date field based on `created_date + months`

So in practicality, that third column would look something like this

[image]

But when I try the way I looked up, it gives me an error:

```
SELECT
DATEADD('month', months, DATE(created_date)) 
FROM
table

ERROR: function date_add(unknown, double precision, date) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Am I just using the wrong type of syntax and there's a different function I should be using?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Error message smells like PG. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080505/dateadd-equivalent-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: based on the error message I assume you are using Postgres.

---

You can [add](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) an `interval` directly to a `date` value. As you have a fixed unit, using `make_interval()` is the easiest way:

```
SELECT date_created + make_interval(months => "months"::integer)
FROM the_table
```

The cast to an `integer` is necessary, because you can't specify fractional months using that function. If you really need that, then multiply the value with an interval of one month:

```
SELECT date_created + months * interval '1 month'
FROM the_table
```

---

In general I would recommend to change the `months` column to an `interval` then you don't need to worry about things like that.